# Problem Unit Test Create Movie to Database

Tags: unit-testing, go

I want to make a unit test to be able to create movies. But I am very confused how to do it.

This is the mock repository

```
// CreateMovie still not complete
func (m *mockMovieRepository) CreateMovie(movie entity.Movie) error {
    args := m.Called(movie)
    return args.Error(0)
}

// CreateMovieGenres still not complete
func (m *mockMovieRepository) CreateMovieGenres(movieGenre entity.MovieGenre) error {
    return nil
}

// GetLastMovies 
func (m *mockMovieRepository) GetLastMovies() (*entity.Movie, error) {
    arguments := m.Called()
    if arguments.Get(0) == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Movie Not Found")
    }else {
        movie := arguments.Get(0).(*entity.Movie)
        return movie, nil
    }
}
```

this is the function of the service section that you want to make a unit test

```
func (service *MovieServiceImpl) CreateMovie(request web.MoviePayloadResponse) error {
    var movieGenre entity.MovieGenre

    //create movie
    movie := movieGenre.Movie   
    movie.ID, _ = strconv.Atoi(request.ID)
    movie.Title = request.Title
    movie.Description = request.Description
    movie.ReleaseDate, _ = time.Parse("2006-01-02", request.ReleaseDate)
    movie.Year = movie.ReleaseDate.Year()
    movie.Runtime, _ = strconv.Atoi(request.Runtime)
    movie.Rating, _ = strconv.Atoi(request.Rating)
    movie.MPAARating = request.MPAARating
    movie.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    movie.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    err := service.Repository.CreateMovie(movie)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //get last movie
    movieLast, err := service.Repository.GetLastMovies()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //create movie genre
    movieGenre.ID, _ = strconv.Atoi(request.ID)
    movieGenre.MovieID = movieLast.ID
    movieGenre.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    movieGenre.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    for _, v := range request.GenreID {
        movieGenre.GenreID, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
        err := service.Repository.CreateMovieGenres(movieGenre)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is the Movie Repository

```
func (MovieRepositoryImpl *MovieRepositoryImpl) CreateMovie(movie entity.Movie) error {
    err := MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.Create(&movie).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then these are the unit tests I've been working on

**GetLastMovie**

```
// GetLastMovie
func TestGetLastMovie(t *testing.T) {
    expectedMovies := &entity.Movie{
        ID: 2, 
        Title: "Movie 2", 
        Description: "Description 2",
    }

    // set up the expectations for the mock repository
    mockRepo.On("GetLastMovies").Return(expectedMovies)
    
    // call the service method
    movies, err := mockService.GetLastMovies()

    // assert the result
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.NotNil(t, movies)
    fmt.Println("Expected ID: " , expectedMovies.ID,  "Actual ID: ", movies.ID)
    fmt.Println("Expected Title: " , expectedMovies.Title, "Actual Title: ", movies.Title)
    fmt.Println("Expected Description: " , expectedMovies.Description, "Actual Description: ", movies.Description)

    assert.Equal(t, expectedMovies.ID, movies.ID)
    assert.Equal(t, expectedMovies.Title, movies.Title)
    assert.Equal(t, expectedMovies.Description, movies.Description)

    mockRepo.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

**GetLastMovie (Not Found)**

```
// GetLastMovie (NOT FOUND)
func TestGetLastMovieNotFound(t *testing.T) {

    // set up the expectations for the mock repository
    mockRepo.On("GetLastMovies").Return(nil)
    
    // call the service method
    movies, err := mockService.GetLastMovies()

    // assert the result
    assert.Nil(t, movies)
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
    fmt.Println(movies, err)
    mockRepo.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

**CreateMovieSuccess** in this unit still Fail

```
// CreateMovieSuccess
func TestCreateMovieSuccess(t *testing.T) {
    db, _ := setupDB()
    truncateDB(db)
    setupRouter(db)

    mockRepo.On("CreateMovie", mock.AnythingOfType("*entity.Movie")).Return(nil)
    mockRepo.On("GetLastMovies").Return(&entity.Movie{ID: 1}, nil)
    mockRepo.On("CreateMovieGenres", mock.AnythingOfType("*entity.MovieGenre")).Return(nil)

    // set up the service
    mockService := &service.MovieServiceImpl{Repository: mockRepo}

    // set up the test request
    request := web.MoviePayloadResponse{
        ID:           "1",
        Title:        "Test Movie",
        Description:  "Test Description",
        ReleaseDate:  "2020-01-01",
        Runtime:      "120",
        Rating:       "8",
        MPAARating:   "R",
        GenreID:      []string{"1", "2"},
    }

    // call the service method
    err := mockService.CreateMovie(request)

    // assert the result
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    mockRepo.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

So my unit test create movies is still failing, how do I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you figure out how it works. First, the solution you've provided in the question is not complete. There are some missing structs/functions/methods definitions. However, based on what you've provided I can do the following considerations.
First, it seems that you didn't clearly understand what a mock is. A mock is a dummy implementation for an actual dependency. This means that if you've to test the `services` layer the only mock needed is for the `repository`. So, the tests have to be done against a real object and not against a mock. The `sut` (System Under Test) should rely on mock in order to avoid the burden of instantiating an actual database for example.
Now I'll try to explain the concept with a practical example. This example is based on a two-packages project:

- the `services` package which is the one we're willing to test (like in your question)
- the `repo` package that provides some capabilities exploited within the `services` package. This package should be mocked for our tests.

##### Production code

The production code only involves two files: `services/service.go` and `repo/repo.go`.

###### `services/service.go`

```golang
package services

import (
    "errors"

    "testifymock/repo"
)

type TeamService struct {
    TR TeamRepoInterface
}

func NewTeamService(repo TeamRepoInterface) *TeamService {
    return &TeamService{
        TR: repo,
    }
}

type TeamRepoInterface interface {
    GetByID(id int) (repo.Team, error)
    Update(team repo.Team) error
}

func (ts *TeamService) Update(team *repo.Team) error {
    t, err := ts.TR.GetByID(team.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if t.TeamOwnerID != team.TeamOwnerID {
        return errors.New("forbidden")
    }

    return ts.TR.Update(*team)
}
```

Here, pay attention to the interface `TeamRepoInterface` which is used to inject the capabilities of the repo into the `services` package.

###### `repo/repo.go`

```golang
package repo

type Team struct {
    ID          int
    TeamOwnerID int
    Name        string
}

type TeamRepo struct{}

func (t *TeamRepo) GetByID(id int) (Team, error) {
    return Team{ID: id, TeamOwnerID: id, Name: "MyTeam"}, nil
}

func (t *TeamRepo) Update(team Team) error {
    return nil
}
```

Here, nothing special to discuss.

##### Test Code

The only test file we've to write is the one for the `services/service.go` file.

###### `services/service_test.go`

```golang
package services

import (
    "errors"
    "testing"

    "testifymock/repo"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

// 1. declare the mock struct
type teamRepoMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

// 2. implement the interface
func (m *teamRepoMock) GetByID(id int) (repo.Team, error) {
    args := m.Called(id)

    return args.Get(0).(repo.Team), args.Error(1)
}

func (m *teamRepoMock) Update(team repo.Team) error {
    args := m.Called(team)

    return args.Error(0)
}

func TestUpdate(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("GoodUpdate", func(t *testing.T) {
        // 3. instantiate/setup mock
        repoMock := new(teamRepoMock)
        repoMock.On("GetByID", 1).Return(repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"}, nil).Times(1)
        repoMock.On("Update", repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"}).Return(nil).Times(1)

        sut := NewTeamService(repoMock)
        err := sut.Update(&repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"})

        // 4. check that all expectations were met on the mock
        assert.Nil(t, err)
        assert.True(t, repoMock.AssertExpectations(t))
    })

    t.Run("BadUpdate", func(t *testing.T) {
        // 3. instantiate/setup mock
        repoMock := new(teamRepoMock)
        repoMock.On("GetByID", 1).Return(repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"}, nil).Times(1)
        repoMock.On("Update", repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"}).Return(errors.New("some error while updating")).Times(1)

        sut := NewTeamService(repoMock)
        err := sut.Update(&repo.Team{ID: 1, TeamOwnerID: 1, Name: "test"})

        // 4. check that all expectations were met on the mock
        assert.Equal(t, "some error while updating", err.Error())
        assert.True(t, repoMock.AssertExpectations(t))
    })
}
```

To be more explicit, I added some comments within the file so you can better understand what's going on.

Let me know if this solves your issue!